# Foreach python file in subdirectory

Tags: makefile

I am throwing the towel with this one.

I have a fairly successful makefile, that finds files in a subdirectory an pass them as filters to pandoc. It works great in paths without spaces, but I cant make it behave in paths that includes spaces.

Here is the MWE:

```
BASEDIR=$(CURDIR)
STYLEDIR=$(BASEDIR)/style
FILFILES := "$(shell find "$(STYLEDIR)" -name *.py)"
FILTER := $(foreach "$(FILFILES)", "$(FILFILES)", --filter $(FILFILES))
TEXFLAGS = --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc $(FILTER) --latex-engine=xelatex

pdf:
    pandoc document.md $(TEXFLAGS)
```

In order for the example to work you have to run the makefile in some directory with spaces, try `this md dir`, create a subdirectory `style` and add any .py file. Now run, and you will see that FILFILES pick the proper python file, but the foreach will create three instances, hence `--filter --filter --filter`. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

In case you want the full makefile: [here](http://pastebin.com/sdrkqXrF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all but impossible to use words (including filenames) containing spaces with make.

To be clear, make completely ignores all types of quoting characters (double, single, back).

In some particular situations you can use tricks to allow it to work.  However you didn't give us any information about what you're actually doing; you show how you assign the variables `FILFILES` and `FILTER` but you don't show how you use those.

If those variables are only used inside recipes then you can often make it work.  If you're using them as prerequisites then it will be very difficult if not impossible.